# Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to set up a simple node backend with Typescript, but I'm having a lot of issues with it. I've read a lot of other threads and tried the suggestions there, but I just keep getting this error.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "../app/**/*"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.25.3",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.17.6"
  }
}
```

I've googled around the issue, and everyone keeps recommending doing exactly what I have done in these configs, and that it then should work, but it doesn't. I additionally updated my node, ts-node and typescript to the latest versions, but still didn't work.

I'm really lost as to what might be the issue here...

Comment: Where/when are you getting this error? How is your project file system defined? EDIT: Oh I see, you are using ts-node instead of compiling TypeScript to JavaScript. I recommend compiling instead of directly using ts-node. ts-node compiles TS to JS so you end doing exactly the same, but with less control of what you are actually doing, hence having these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest version of node ( 20.0.0 at the time of writing ) had some breaking changes apparently, as I found out on the ts-node github issues section. I downgraded my node version to LTS ( 18.16.0 at the time of writing ), and my issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you! I also had Node v20 installed, and downgrading to v18 worked. Now, what is that breaking change and how to solve it?